# push_back causing sgfault

Tags: c++, std

I have a class ArbDouble, made by me, which is basically a wrapper for a [mpfr_t](http://www.mpfr.org/)

The relevant part of the class for this problem is

```
class ArbDouble
{
private:
    mpfr_t value;

public:
    explicit ArbDouble(long double value_, unsigned long precision) {
        mpfr_init2(value, precision);
        mpfr_set_d(value, value_, MPFR_RNDN);
    }
    explicit ArbDouble(long int value_, unsigned long precision) {
        mpfr_init2(value, precision);
        mpfr_set_ui(value, value_, MPFR_RNDN);
    }

    ArbDouble(){
        mpfr_init(value);
    }

    ArbDouble(unsigned long precision) {
        mpfr_init2(value,precision);
    }
    ArbDouble(const ArbDouble& other) {
        mpfr_init2(value, other.getPrecision());
        mpfr_set(value, other.value, MPFR_RNDN);
    }

    ArbDouble(const mpfr_t& other) {
        mpfr_init2(value, mpfr_get_prec(other));
        mpfr_set(value, other, MPFR_RNDN);
    }

    explicit ArbDouble(char* other, unsigned long precision) {
        mpfr_init2(value, precision);
        mpfr_set_str(value, other, 10, MPFR_RNDN);
    }

    ~ArbDouble() {
        mpfr_clear(value);
    }

    inline unsigned long getPrecision() const
    {
        return mpfr_get_prec(value);
    }
    inline ArbDouble& operator=(const ArbDouble &other)
    {
        mpfr_set_prec(value, other.getPrecision());
        mpfr_set(value, other.value, MPFR_RNDN);
        return *this;
    }
}
```

Now, I'm using std::vector to store a matrix of these values e.g.

```
std::vector<ArbDouble> temp;
temp.push_back(ArbDouble((long int)0,64)); // calling "ArbDouble(long int value_, unsigned long precision)"

std::vector<std::vector<ArbDouble> > currentOrbit;
currentOrbit.push_back(temp);
```

and this causes a segfault on a linux machine, but not on a mac machine.

The error given by gdb is:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004069fe in std::vector<std::vector<ArbDouble, std::allocator<ArbDouble> >, std::allocator<std::vector<ArbDouble, std::allocator<ArbDouble> > > >::push_back (this=0xb5daafcc938b13f6, __x=std::vector of length 1, capacity 1 = {...})
    at /usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/stl_vector.h:743
743     if (this->_M_impl._M_finish != this->_M_impl._M_end_of_storage)
```

Does anyone knows where the problem can be? I'm not a very good class designer, so, my guess is that somewhere it has a flaw. Any suggestions to it are very welcome!!!

Comment: Can you construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org)?  i.e. the shortest possible program that still causes the bug?

Comment: `explicit` only has an effect on single-argument constructors. It won't ever cause a crash of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a typical case of heap/stack corruption. You probably have an array somewhere that you are writing to, but out of its boundaries. Doing so, you are changing variables of random nearby objects (in this case the `vector`) and hence the strange errors on internals of some other library (in this case `std`).

Since all your class does is call this `mpfr_` set of functions, most probably the error is there (unless there is some other code that you are not showing). You could try debugging and finding out the problem in any way you like, but perhaps the easiest solution would be to use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/):

```
valgrind --leak-check=full ./your_program --args --to --your program
```

Comment: You are probably right. I will check valgrind, but on my mac I checked memory leaks, and used the guard malloc library to check boundary of pointers.

Comment: Valgrind does not give any significant errors (only unitialized and stuff), but more importantly, the code runs: it does not give any segfault... -.- WTF?

Comment: @J.C.Leitão, the fact that it doesn't segfault is not surprising. When you have done something that results in "undefined behavior", anything could happen. Most specifically, behavior could change if `-g` options is disabled/enabled etc.

Comment: I'm not sure why you say they are not significant, but using uninitialized variables is a pretty serious crime.

Comment: yeah, but the unitialized was not a danger in this case. Anyway, I tried to create an test-code with the error, and it was not reproduced, so it must be a very well hidden error. Thanks for your help, this question solved the problem (or at least said it was not what I though).